# Not all tags show up in question overview

Tags: support, status-completed, tagging, search

I just did a search on [is:q wheelchair](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+wheelchair).

This is one of the questions that shows up:

[image]

This shows tags [air-travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-travel) and [aircraft](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aircraft).
However, when I click through to [the question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/147338/do-wheelchair-accessible-aircrafts-exist?r=SearchResults&s=6|45.1788)
this shows **three** tags: [air-travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-travel), [aircraft](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aircraft) and [accessibility](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accessibility):

[image]

**Why the discrepancy?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most probably a caching issue. Search result caching does not get refreshed as often as questions and answers. If you wait a few hours the problems should most probably disappear.

Comment: That's it, yes. The [revision history for the question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/147338/revisions) shows that the edit adding the tag *accessibility* [was approved](https://travel.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/125486) 9 minutes before my question here **by me** and Daniil (blush) ;-) I did remember approving a question about accessibility some time earlier, but not that it was this one.